# Paperclip (imagemagick) generates dark images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm using paperclip gem to resize images.
The issue is that resized images are "dark". I attached two examples of the original image and the resized one.

Here is the code generating images :

```
has_attached_file :result,
  :styles => {
    :medium => { :geometry => '262' },
  },
  :hash_secret => "xxx",
  :url => "/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:hash.:extension",
  :hash_data => ":class/:attachment/:style/:id"
validates_attachment :result, :content_type => { :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/ }
```

I can see this line in the log :

```
Command :: convert '/tmp/xxx.png[0]' -auto-orient -resize "262" '/tmp/xxx20150110-9669-z4rtiy'
```

[image: Original image]

[image: Resized image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying adding `-colorspace sRGB` into your `convert` command like this to *force* the colorspace:

```
convert input.png -resize 262 -colorspace sRGB output.png
```

Your command works fine on my (very current) version of ImageMagick as is, but if I put `-colorspace RGB` it comes out dark here too. I believe the default colorspace changed in recent versions of IM.